# Show Window from Grid Cell? EXTjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Grid and Window/Form definded on a page.. one of the grid columns is effectively an 'action' column.. i need to write an href or js for each cell in this column which will show the Extjs 'action' window and pass it the cell data..

I'm having trouble finding the correct renderer or handler approach.. Does a simple example exist? Ultimately I'd just like to render the data to link within the cell and have that click show an already defined Extjs window with the cell data..

ExtJS 3.4

any direction or examples are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can register a listener for the `cellclick` event on the grid.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick